# Struggling to .Dispose() using return method with PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, .net, puppeteer-sharp

I'm struggling to `.Dispose()` and Chromium is building up and crashing my computer because this is a process that is left on for days.

However, I cannot put `.Dispose()` after `return` because it'll be unreachable, and if I put it before `return`, the content string will become stale.

```
    var docBContent = await renderHtmlAsync(url2);
    fromDoc.LoadHtml(docBContent);

public static async Task<string> renderHtmlAsync(string url2)
{
    await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);
    Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
    {
        Headless = true
    });
    var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
    page.DefaultTimeout = 0;
    var navigation = new NavigationOptions
    {
        Timeout = 0,
        WaitUntil = new[] {
                WaitUntilNavigation.DOMContentLoaded }
    };
    await page.GoToAsync(url2, navigation);
    var content = page.GetContentAsync();

    return await content;
}
```

This is what appears, including with the solutions mentioned so far:
[image]

How do I tackle this?

Comment: A little note: `return await content;` looks strange, because the variable named content, you "can't" await content. It's confusing... You await the `GetContentAsync()` method. I would change it to `return await page.GetContentAsync()`

Comment: Instead of using a browser to get content, you could also use the [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) which is much more lightweight.

Comment: I've changed the return - unfortunately, the site I'm scraping is in React and the content is after load - so headless is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `using` block for that:

```
public static async Task<string> renderHtmlAsync(string url2)
{
    await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);
    using (Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
    {
        Headless = true
    }))
    {
        var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        page.DefaultTimeout = 0;
        var navigation = new NavigationOptions
        {
            Timeout = 0,
            WaitUntil = new[] {
                    WaitUntilNavigation.DOMContentLoaded }
        };
        await page.GoToAsync(url2, navigation);
        var content = page.GetContentAsync();

        return await content;
    }
}
```

This works like:

```
var myObject = new DispoableObject();
try
{
    // insert code
    return result;
}
finally
{
    myObject.Dispose();
}
```

The code in the finally is always executed, even when an exception is thrown inside the try block.

Comment: Are you saying the top block of code will deal with the issue? No need to manually add dispose? Sorry - I'm slightly confused.

Comment: Yes, the `using` statement `using (Browser browser = ` will dispose the browser.

Comment: I've uploaded an image from the last 24 hours @Jeroen Van Langen. The program ran for two hours and crashed, it still doesn't look like it's closing chromium using your top block of code.

Comment: What about using the HttpClient instead?

Comment: This works if you use finally too (the second block of code aswell). I apologize, I was being an idiot.